# Why is this URL can not be used on Highstock?

Tags: url, highcharts

It is not working when I use this URL on Highstock.
http://www.xhychina.org/index.php?m=dbsource&c=call&a=get&id=1

```
$(function() {
    var url = "http://www.xhychina.org/index.php?m=dbsource&c=call&a=get&id=1";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            series : [{
                name : '指数',
                data : dataz,
                gapSize: 5,
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                tooltip: {
                    xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            }]


        });


    });

});
```

Thx for your help！

Answer (score 0):

For me it works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/301/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [[1351728000000,100],[1351814400000,100],[1352073600000,99],[1352160000000,99],[1352246400000,98],[1352332800000,96],[1352419200000,96],[1352678400000,98],[1352764800000,97],[1352851200000,97],[1352937600000,97],[1353024000000,98],[1353283200000,99],[1353369600000,98],[1353456000000,98],[1353542400000,97],[1353628800000,96],[1353888000000,95],[1353974400000,91],[1354060800000,90],[1354147200000,88],[1354233600000,90],[1354492800000,88],[1354579200000,89],[1354665600000,92],[1354752000000,92],[1354838400000,95],[1355097600000,96],[1355184000000,95],[1355270400000,96],[1355356800000,95],[1355443200000,99],[1355702400000,98],[1355788800000,97],[1355875200000,98],[1355961600000,99],[1356048000000,99],[1356307200000,99],[1356393600000,101],[1356480000000,103],[1356566400000,102],[1356652800000,103],[1356912000000,107],[1357257600000,106],[1357516800000,107],[1357603200000,108],[1357689600000,108],[1357776000000,108],[1357862400000,105],[1358121600000,110],[1358208000000,116],[1358294400000,114],[1358380800000,112],[1358467200000,115],[1358726400000,116],[1358812800000,113],[1358899200000,114],[1358985600000,112],[1359072000000,112],[1359331200000,114],[1359417600000,115],[1359504000000,115],[1359590400000,116],[1359676800000,118],[1359936000000,117],[1360022400000,118],[1360108800000,120],[1360195200000,122],[1360281600000,123],[1361145600000,126],[1361232000000,124],[1361318400000,130],[1361404800000,130],[1361491200000,129],[1361750400000,138],[1361836800000,134],[1361923200000,135],[1362009600000,138],[1362096000000,146],[1362355200000,147],[1362441600000,150],[1362528000000,149],[1362614400000,142],[1362700800000,141],[1362960000000,143],[1363046400000,139],[1363132800000,137],[1363219200000,137],[1363305600000,139],[1363564800000,142],[1363651200000,141],[1363737600000,145],[1363824000000,152],[1363910400000,150],[1364169600000,150],[1364256000000,148],[1364342400000,148],[1364428800000,144],[1364515200000,142],[1364774400000,146],[1364860800000,142],[1364947200000,139],[1365379200000,141],[1365465600000,143],[1365552000000,140],[1365638400000,141],[1365724800000,138],[1365984000000,137],[1366070400000,139],[1366156800000,141],[1366243200000,144],[1366329600000,147],[1366588800000,148],[1366675200000,143],[1366761600000,146],[1366848000000,142],[1366934400000,137],[1367452800000,138],[1367539200000,142],[1367798400000,145],[1367884800000,149],[1367971200000,149],[1368057600000,152],[1368144000000,153],[1368403200000,153],[1368489600000,149],[1368576000000,153],[1368662400000,154],[1368748800000,155],[1369008000000,158],[1369094400000,163],[1369180800000,159],[1369267200000,158],[1369353600000,160],[1369612800000,164],[1369699200000,162],[1369785600000,164],[1369872000000,164],[1369958400000,167],[1370217600000,164],[1370304000000,161],[1370390400000,161],[1370476800000,157],[1370563200000,154],[1371081600000,152],[1371168000000,157],[1371427200000,156],[1371513600000,156],[1371600000000,154],[1371686400000,147],[1371772800000,146],[1372032000000,135],[1372118400000,137],[1372204800000,142],[1372291200000,143],[1372377600000,142],[1372636800000,146],[1372723200000,148],[1372809600000,147],[1372896000000,146],[1372982400000,144],[1373241600000,137],[1373328000000,138],[1373414400000,143]]       
    }]
});
```